# How to add discount programmatically in drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

I have custom staff interface where staff select products and select discount for overall order. On click of submit all data are passed in json format to drupal custom menu.

Custom function correctly create order, product, tax.  Below is custom function which is called on submit

```
function add_to_cart() {
  $reservationData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  foreach($reservationData as $key => $values) {
  if (!empty($values->rooms)) {
    foreach ($values->rooms as $k => $v) {
      .... //more code
      $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
      $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, 0, array(), 'roomify_accommodation_booking');
      $ntype = array('target_id'=> $product_id);
      // Add line item to cart.
      $line_item = commerce_cart_product_add($userID, $line_item, FALSE);
      .... //more code
      //calculate tax rate for each line item
      $taxRates = commerce_tax_rates();
      commerce_tax_rate_apply($taxRates["room_tax"], $line_item);
      commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
    }
   }
  }
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($userID);
  $order->status = 'pending';
  commerce_order_save($order);
}
```

Even after adding below code it give me error

```
// Add the line item to the order using the wrapper.
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  commerce_discount_fixed_amount($order_wrapper, 'discount_test_discount');
```

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function commerce_discount_fixed_amount() in **../sites/all/modules/reservation/reservation.module** on line **145**

how should I apply DISCOUNT on overall total amount?.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried what you are trying to achieve.
You need to enable the commerce_discount module in order to use the function (commerce_discount_fixed_amount).